# Is it possible to install Symantec Endpoint protection manager without trusted root / ca certificates

Tags: certificate, anti-virus, symantec

I am trying to install Symantec end point protection manager on Server 2012 R2 without trusted root or CA certificates in an environment that is air gapped has no internet access and absolutely no certificates in the registry path: C:\Program Files\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\14.3.8268.5000.105\bin64\EFAInst64.exe is not trusted. Verification result: 20

We have tried using dvd and usb media but we keep getting the installer integrity check failed with error code 0x800b0004. Common causes for this failure include an incomplete download, damaged media, or problems with Trusted Root Certificate store.

The broadcom portal suggests checking this https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?articleId=170150

But as we do not use certificates we cannot do that. Has anyone out there installed Symantec Endpoint Protection manager without certificates please? Thanks in advance S.P.

WE have tried burning the media and copying to usb, downloaded the said certificates and put them in the mmc store which did not work

However we cannot do the below as we do not have any registry keyes in the below path.

Open regedt32.exe or regedit.exe as an administrator and browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPublisher As a precaution you should export the TrustedPublisher key and save it as a REG-file so that it may be restored at a later time. Under TrustedPublisher locate the Safer key and delete it. Install SEP

Comment: It has been a while since I used Symantec Endpoint. I do not think you can install it without Internet. Most A/V is like that, especially for servers.

Comment: SEPM connects to the cloud and SEP client can get their updates from the SEPM. Use a different dedicated machine newer Windows Server OS too preferably with what it needs to access out to the Internet allow listed and block everything else. Otherwise, look into SES Cloud and have endpoint get policies and definition updates right from the cloud. You can deploy SES Agent via those and discovery or remote PowerShell commands from your trusted network. @SasParmar